# Legacy file_column plugin is not finding files in paths it created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm debugging a legacy rails application which is not finding files in paths that were created by the same application on a different server.

Uploaded files are stored by the file_column plugin in paths like this:

```
document/file/0001/1112/pic1.jpg
document/file/0001/1113/pic2.jpg
document/file/0001/1114/pic3.jpg
document/file/0002/1112/pic4.jpg
```

I assume this is a strategy for managing many files when there are too many for a single folder. There are several thousand four-digit subdirectories in each zero-padded parent directory.

The system serves the URLs with a single ID that matches the combined directory structure, e.g. for pic1 it points the browser to:

mydomain.com/document/file/11112/pic1.jpg

Unfortunately the corresponding files are not being found under the split directory structure. I don't know if the URL is being generated wrongly or the interpretation across split file paths is supposed to happen automatically but isn't currently.

If I upload a new image, the system saves it in a directory with unsplit name:

```
document/file/21113/pic5.jpg
```

Newly uploaded images are served without problems from this sort of path.

What is likely responsible for splitting the directories (Rails, the server OS, file_column plugin, application itself?), and how do I restore things so that it can continue serving the old files?

Comment: At first guess i would say the plugin is responsible. Looking through the source the for plugin [this line](https://github.com/rust/file_column/blob/285189b0147373137c120dacc3215872c96922c9/lib/file_column.rb#L402) seems to be giving the id in the path as your newly uploaded images are. My first guess was that it must have changed at some point from `/0000/0001/` format to the `/1/` format but there is no such history in the commit log for the gem.

Comment: I guess you have two choices in fixing it. Make your own fork of the gem and change the code to match your current file structure. Or change the folder structure to match what the gem puts out(you probably wanna set up some redirects to handle hard-linked images).

Comment: Are you using the same version of the gem as the legacy system was?